# Audio is not playing without breakpoint

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, ios13

The sound file is playing when i add breakpoints inside the below functions. But the sound file is not playing if i run the application without breakpoint.

I am calling this function in button click as  Sound().playSounds()

```
import AVFoundation

class Sound {

    private var audioplayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    func playSounds()
    {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Audio/ring.mp3", ofType: nil)
        {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            do {
                self.audioplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                self.audioplayer.numberOfLoops = 3
                self.audioplayer.prepareToPlay()
                self.audioplayer.play()
                }

            catch {
                print("Couldn't load  file")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Sound` object gets deallocated before it has a chance to play a sound.

Store it where you are calling it from:

```
var sound = Sound()

// for example to play sound call 
func playPressed(){
  sound.playSounds()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chane your player into a global variable like this. Otherwise it'll be a deadlock.

```
var audioplayer:AVAudioPlayer!
```

Also you may want to change your resource path extracting logic to below,

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "ring.mp3", ofType: "mp3")
```

Or you can directly use `Bundle.main.url(forResource: withExtention)` method.

Comment: I need to play ringtone while showing the swiftui class. So that i have added the below code in the .onAppear { if let pathurl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Audio/ring", withExtension: "mp3") { do { self.audioplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: pathurl) self.audioplayer.prepareToPlay() self.audioplayer.numberOfLoops = 3 print("Playing") self.audioplayer.play() } catch { print("Couldn't load file") } } }. The Playing is printing in the xcode console. But it is not ringing. I declare  @State private var audioplayer:AVAudioPlayer! in top of swiftui class.

Comment: One more thing, From the swift class file, i am showing the swiftui like DispatchQueue.main.async{ let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first let contentView = IncomingCallView(viewNavigator: ViewNavigator()) window?.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView:contentView) window?.makeKeyAndVisible() }   The audio player is called in the IncomingCallView of onAppear method, But it is not playing,